# How do you format partial song lyrics at the beginning of a chapter

Tags: formatting, citations

How do I format and cite partial song lyrics at the beginning of a chapter?
Can all lines be centered?

e.g.:

> **Chapter 19**
>
> **Sweet Dreams**
>
> Sweet dreams are made of this
>
> Who am I to disagree?
>
> I travel the world
>
> And the seven seas,
>
> Everybody's looking for something
>
> Eurythmics

Comment: I found a link that may help you.  It seems the best advice would be along the lines of what surtsey said.  It seems fairly costly for people to do lyrics and I doubt most new or unknown writers have the ability to pay the required fees and royalties.  http://mademers.com/the-perils-of-using-song-lyrics-in-your-book/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and italicized, if you wish. Stephen King staggered NIN lyrics in The Dark Tower series; others have put them justified left. I would, however, not double space them, as it makes it seem like poetry.

Comment: While this directly answers the question, it should be noted to readers and the OP that adding in lyrics to a book can be very costly as I have found multiple sources citing the advice against such practices unless you have the means to afford it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you may format the lyrics any way that pleases you.

The long answer is: don't do it at all!

Permissions for the use of song lyrics are extremely hard to get (Why would the Eurythmics want to associate themselves with you?).

If you obtain permission: the first thing to do is to refinance you house.

For one line of “Jumpin’ Jack Flash”: £500

For one line of Oasis’s “Wonderwall”: £535

For one line of “When I’m Sixty-four”: £735.

For two lines of “I Shot the Sheriff” £1,000.

Note: that's pounds-sterling no US dollars!

Comment: Can you cite a source for those numbers? Not that I doubt you, it is just useful to know where they come from.

Comment: Goodbye Emily - Michael Murphy.

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't know how credible the guardian is... but it seems this article is where he got his figures... https://www.theguardian.com/books/2010/may/01/blake-morrison-lyrics-copyright

Comment: Also bumping this answer... while it does not answer the question on how to format lyrics in a book, it is advice worth listening to for people interested in doing this.  Though, this probably would have been better as a comment since it is not an answer to the question.